# ng-model - bind to dynamic field in object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have this code:

```
  <div ng-repeat="c in q.children | orderBy:[]">

      <div ng-if="c.kind == 'text'">
        <label>
          {{c.value}}
          <textarea ng-model="q.newResponse.value['{{c._id}}']"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>

  // ...
```

What I am trying to do is bind a property on `newReponse.value`, where that property is dynamic and is the `c._id` value, so something like:

```
newResponse.value.44PkfeoakfoAf5o3r3773oZS3a = 'foo bar baz';
```

This doesn't work as is, and I get this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 22 of the expression [q.newResponse.value[{{c._id}}]] starting at [{c._id}}]].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=22&p3=q.newResponse.value%5B%7B%7Bc._id%7D%7D%5D&p4=%7Bc._id%7D%7D%5D
    at angular.js:68
    at AST.throwError (angular.js:14893)
    at AST.object (angular.js:14882)
```

Is this possible and what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, that wasn't so hard -

```
      <div ng-if="c.kind == 'text'">
        <label>
          {{c.value}}
          <textarea ng-model="q.newResponse.value[c._id]"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
```